# dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid how do i set a noDataMessage?

Tags: grid, store, dojo

I'm trying to set a `noDataMessage` into a `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid`, the grid works fine, when the store get data it show it's row with no problem, but I need that when the store gets no data the grid would show me a personalized message. I set the `noDataMessage` property which is a string, but nothing happened when has no data.

How can I trigger the event when no data in the store?

I get my data through a SQL query to a database and the answer is JSON serialized data.

here's the code of my grid.

```
    intersGrid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
//        plugins: {dnd: true},viewInterconsulta
        id :"intersGrid",
        store: interfiltStore,
        structure: intersLayout,
        noDataMessage:"<span class=\"dojoxGridNoData\">No hay Datos</span>",
        loadingMessage:'Cargando datos. Por favor espere.',
        //noDataMessage: 'No existen pacientes esta agenda.',
        errorMessage:'No existen datos para esta busqueda.'
    }, "intersDiv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.
What you have to do is.

if you get an empty store then set them like these:

**$filas = "{ identifier: 'ID', items[]}";

**json_encode($filas)."}";**

and then dojo shows the noDataMessage

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only showed 25 rows and then requested with help of offset & count another 25 when scrolling down the list. In this case, I needed "numRows" - which is the total amount of rows, leaving out offset & count. The "numRows" was set to 0 if no rows where found. But if it was given, the noDataMessage was not shown (btw: An "identifier" is not required).

Also there is a syntax error in your json, add some ":" after "items".

This is the JSON for the store, which shows the noDataMessage of a dojox datagrid:

```
{"items":[]}
```

This will not show it:

```
{"items":[],"numRows":"0"}
```

*Using Dojo 1.6.1, a dojox.grid.DataGrid with a dojox.data.QueryReadStore*